# Динамическое создание кнопок и изменение их цвета по нажатию

Tags: c++, qt

у меня создаются динамически кнопки (добавляется по одной по нажатию на другую кнопку "Добавить").
Далее по нажатию на эти кнопки мне нужно менять цвет каждой, сейчас у меня получается менять цвет только последней созданной кнопки (как я понимаю, дело в том, что slot вызывается к последнему указателю), как мне это исправить, подскажите пожалуйста?

Заголовочный файл .h

```
private:
QPushButton *buttonForColor;

private slots:
void addNewRowToTable();
void setColor();
```

Кнопка "Добавить" для создания кнопок

```
QPushButton *addRowInTable = new QPushButton("Добавить", this);
connect(addRowInTable, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(addNewRowToTable()));
```

Далее, по нажатию, срабатывает функция добавления

```
void SParametrs::addNewRowToTable()
{
 buttonForColor = new QPushButton;
 connect(buttonForColor, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(setColor()));  
}
```

И теперь, по нажатию на созданные кнопки, срабатывает функция установки цвета конкретной кнопки

```
void SParametrs::setColor() {
QColor color = QColorDialog::getColor(Qt::green, this);

QPalette palette = buttonForColor->palette();
palette.setColor(QPalette::Button,color);
buttonForColor->setStyleSheet("background-color:" + color.name());
}
```

Как мне поправить, чтобы я мог ставить цвет на любую кнопку из созданных, а не только на последнюю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваше предположение неверно. Слот срабатывает для каждой из кнопок. Проблема в самом слоте. Вы изменяете там объект buttonForColor, указатель которого изменяется при создании новой кнопки (поэтому и указывает на последнюю кнопку). Чтобы манипулировать объектом-инициатором сигнала в слоте, привязанном к нескольким объектам, вам надо получать указатель на объект-отправитель:

```
void SParametrs::setColor() {
   QColor color = QColorDialog::getColor(Qt::green, this);
   QPalette palette = buttonForColor->palette();
   palette.setColor(QPalette::Button,color);
   QPushButton* button = (QPushButton*)sender(); //!!
   button->setStyleSheet("background-color:" + color.name());
}
```

Comment: Более корректно было бы использовать qobject_cast<QPushButton*> и проверку на соответствие типа, вместо форсированного каста (еще и в синтаксисе C)